# How to write generic functions in Kotlin interfaces's implementations

Tags: kotlin, generics

I am trying to implement a generic HttpClient like this one:

```
interface HttpClient {
    fun <T: Any> get(url: String): T?
}
```

implemented by a class like this:

```
class HttpClientImpl @Inject constructor(...) : HttpClient {

    override fun <T : Any> get(url: String): T? = execute(url)
    
    private inline fun <reified T: Any> execute(url: String): T? {
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).get().build()
        client.newCall(request).execute().use {
            return it.body?.parseBodySuccess()
        }
    }

    private inline fun <reified T: Any> ResponseBody?.parseBody(): T? {
        val type = objectMapper.typeFactory.constructType(T::class.java)
        return this?.let { objectMapper.readValue(it.string(), type) }
    }

}
```

Now, I would like to be able to call such GET method in this way:

```
data class MyEntity(...)

class MyService @Inject constructor(private val client: HttpClient) {
    fun performGet(url: String): MyEntity? = client.get<MyEntity>(url)
}
```

However this is not allowed and the compiler throws an error referring to the line of code

```
override fun <T : Any> get(endpoint: String): T? = execute(endpoint)
```

flagging that : **Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.**

I have been trying to re-write the line as

```
override inline fun <reified T : Any> get(endpoint: String): T? = execute(endpoint)
```

however, despite having to make the other two inline functions "non private" the compiler still won't compile because in this last way of writing the overriding function, it says:

**Override by a function with reified type parameter**

How can I achieve such generic function?

Comment: It's not a good idea to use a chain of inline functions just because you need one reified parameter. I suggest that everything should actually have a `Class<T>` argument, then you can create an inline extension of get with reified parameter that will call through to `get(url, T::class.java)`.

Comment: Hi @Pawel sorry that I get back to you only now. Thanks for your comment, at the end yesterday after reading around about inline functions I realized that too (that's not a good idea to have inline functions for the sake of it...). About the generic function, among the several trials I made I also tried something similar to what I guess you are referring to... I will post a snippet of what I did, and that for now is working however, if you or anyone else know a better way, please let me know. In any case, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something like this:

```
interface HttpClient {
    fun <T: Any> get(url: String, type: Class<T>): T?
}
```

implemented as:

```
class HttpClientImpl @Inject constructor(...) : HttpClient {

    override fun <T : Any> get(url: String, type: Class<T>): T? = execute(url, type)
    
    private fun <T: Any> execute(url: String, type: Class<T>): T? {
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).get().build()
        client.newCall(request).execute().use {
            return it.body?.parseBody(type)
        }
    }

    private fun <T: Any> ResponseBody?.parseBody(type: Class<T>): T? {
        val dataType = objectMapper.typeFactory.constructType(type)
        return this?.let { objectMapper.readValue(it.string(), dataType) }
    }

}
```

that I can call in this way:

```
data class MyEntity(...)

class MyService @Inject constructor(private val client: HttpClient) {
    fun performGet(url: String): MyEntity? = client.get(url, MyEntity::class.java)
}
```

I would have preferred to pass the Type directly as an actual type like

```
client.get<MyEntity>(url)
```

rather than passing the Class as a parameter, however, just for now it works...

If anyone can suggest a better way of doing this, please let me know.

**Updated**

As suggested by Pawel, I have created an extra inline extension function to the HttpClient interface

```
inline fun <reified T:Any> HttpClient.get (url: String) = get(url, T::class.java)
```

And I'm now able to call the function the way I wanted.

Comment: As I mentioned you can create an extension function. Outside your interface body add `inline fun <reified T : Any> HttpClient.get(endpoint: String) = get(endpoint, T::class.java)` then you'll be able to call it as you desire.

Comment: I see, got it, it works like a charm, thanks @Pawel